# Unable to communicate with node pacemaker during authorization

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos7, cluster, pacemaker

I'm building a pacemaker practise lab of two nodes, using CentOS 7.1 virtual machines.

following instruction from below link, I have installed pacemaker pcs and resource-agents
added host to `/etc/hosts`.
turned off both firewalld and selinux
after starting pcsd service, tried

```
pcs cluster auth node1 node2 -u hacluster -p password --debug
```

got following output,

```
Running: /usr/bin/ruby -I/usr/lib/pcsd/ /usr/lib/pcsd/pcsd-cli.rb auth
Environment:
  GEM_HOME=/usr/lib/pcsd/vendor/bundle/ruby
  HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
  HISTSIZE=1000
  HOME=/root
  HOSTNAME=node2
  LANG=en_IN
  LC_ALL=C
  LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
  LOGNAME=root
  LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:
  MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root
  OLDPWD=/var/log
  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
  PCSD_DEBUG=true
  PCSD_NETWORK_TIMEOUT=60
  PWD=/var/log/pcsd
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  SHLVL=1
  SSH_CLIENT=192.168.122.1 38770 22
  SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.122.1 38770 192.168.122.82 22
  SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
  TERM=xterm-256color
  USER=root
  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
  XDG_SESSION_ID=6
  _=/usr/sbin/pcs
--Debug Input Start--
{"username": "hacluster", "local": false, "nodes": ["node1", "node2"], "password": "redhat", "force": true}
--Debug Input End--

Finished running: /usr/bin/ruby -I/usr/lib/pcsd/ /usr/lib/pcsd/pcsd-cli.rb auth
Return value: 0
--Debug Stdout Start--
{
  "status": "ok",
  "data": {
    "auth_responses": {
      "node1": {
        "status": "noresponse"
      },
      "node2": {
        "status": "noresponse"
      }
    },
    "sync_successful": true,
    "sync_nodes_err": [

    ],
    "sync_responses": {
    }
  },
  "log": [
    "I, [2018-04-18T23:13:56.818854 #14115]  INFO -- : PCSD Debugging enabled\n",
    "D, [2018-04-18T23:13:56.819083 #14115] DEBUG -- : Did not detect RHEL 6\n",
    "I, [2018-04-18T23:13:56.819116 #14115]  INFO -- : Running: /usr/sbin/corosync-cmapctl totem.cluster_name\n",
    "I, [2018-04-18T23:13:56.819134 #14115]  INFO -- : CIB USER: hacluster, groups: \n",
    "D, [2018-04-18T23:13:56.820915 #14115] DEBUG -- : []\n",
    "D, [2018-04-18T23:13:56.820969 #14115] DEBUG -- : [\"Failed to initialize the cmap API. Error CS_ERR_LIBRARY\\n\"]\n",
    "D, [2018-04-18T23:13:56.821009 #14115] DEBUG -- : Duration: 0.001766521s\n",
    "I, [2018-04-18T23:13:56.821046 #14115]  INFO -- : Return Value: 1\n",
    "W, [2018-04-18T23:13:56.821081 #14115]  WARN -- : Cannot read config 'corosync.conf' from '/etc/corosync/corosync.conf': No such file\n",
    "W, [2018-04-18T23:13:56.821113 #14115]  WARN -- : Cannot read config 'corosync.conf' from '/etc/corosync/corosync.conf': No such file or directory - /etc/corosync/corosync.conf\n",
    "I, [2018-04-18T23:13:57.057300 #14115]  INFO -- : No response from: node1 request: auth, error: ssl_connect_error\n",
    "I, [2018-04-18T23:13:57.057423 #14115]  INFO -- : No response from: node2 request: auth, error: ssl_connect_error\n"
  ]
}

--Debug Stdout End--
--Debug Stderr Start--

--Debug Stderr End--

Error: Unable to communicate with node1
Error: Unable to communicate with node2
```

link: https://clusterlabs.org/quickstart-redhat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

upgrade it to CentOS 7.4 or later. there's some issue with packages that need  selinux-policy 7.4 packages in CentOS 7.1. ( not an expert ).